# Struggling with Interactions and Effects when coding

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I don't think there is a better place to ask than here. I enjoy coding but I feel like I'm having an uphill battle when I'm getting to the interaction and effect part of various functions, what sort of knowledge is it that I'm having a hard time with? Is It data structures? I'd like to be able to nail this easily, everything else seems like a breeze, so any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you give an example of where you're having trouble? E.g. code you don't understand or code you're not sure how to write?

Comment: It's just in general, let's say I'm writing a function, I define the arguments visibility, checks etc. when I get to the interact and effect part of the function it starts to become uphill struggle.

Comment: Perhaps there's something you're reading that confuses you? Without being more specific, I'm afraid it's hard to answer the question. Perhaps you could just write out your understanding of the Checks-Effects-Interactions pattern and get feedback on whether your understanding is correct?

Comment: Could you perhaps explain the Check-Effect-Interaction pattern? This is what we get of information from the solidity docs, checks are clear, could you perhaps provide me a more detailed explanation of effect & interaction?

"checks (who called the function, are the arguments in range, did they send enough Ether, does the person have tokens, etc.). These checks should be done first.

As the second step, if all checks passed, effects to the state variables of the current contract should be made. Interaction with other contracts should be the very last step in any function."

Comment: Does https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/05/writing-a-banking-contract/ help? Particularly the "avoiding the reentrancy vulnerability" section.

Comment: This is a great website in general, I've read this post previously, however it does not help me get a more clear understanding of effects and interactions

Comment: Ah, sorry it didn't help. Maybe we'll try to write a deeper post about the pattern. Effects are updates to internal state (e.g. updating an account's balance). Interactions are calls to other contracts (e.g. simple transfers or invoking functions in another contract). I hope that helps more.

Comment: please do, it's missing out there and people come from so many backgrounds into this new world!